# Struts 2 file upload - missing attached file after coming with action errors

Tags: java, file-upload, web, struts2

I have a form (JSP) with multiple Struts2 controls. There is a file upload input as well. Once I submit the form if it has errors, the action will be redirected to the same form with those errors. In this occasion all the previously filled form fields remain except for the file upload input item. It displays no file selected, instead it should show the previously attached file. All the other aspects are working fine except for this.

Comment: This is how file input works. You cannot re-populate it because of the security reasons.

Comment: Perform the submission asynchronously, or at least perform the validation asynchronously and block submission until then.